# Android Here premium sdk - change directory for offline maps for

Tags: android, here-api, here-maps-rest

I succesfully downloaded offline map for a country with here premium sdk on android, but it looks that it was stored to internal app directory, is there any way to change the directory ? What is the default directory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MapSettings.setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath(String path) to set desired cache location. It is recommended to set the disk cache location under your application directory if you do not want the cache to persist after your app is uninstalled. This call should occur before MapEngine initialization, otherwise private app's directory will be used for disk cache. For example, if you are modifying the application from the sample tutorial app, you can add the call in the BasicMapActivity.java file before mapFragment.init().

See documentation here: https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.15/dev_guide/topics/map-service.html